# Got the same Threadlocal for different sessions

Tags: java, session, thread-local

I've sent the same request to a Spring MVC project with two browsers, but I got the same threadlocal, so the instances in threadlocal are the same.，Why?

Comment: Probably because you are not properly clearing them after serving requests?

Answer (score 3):

Threadlocal is bound to a thread / process, not to a session. JVM does not really know or care about the concept of web sessions, that's a higher level of abstraction.

It is well possible that two web requests with two sessions are handled by the same thread. Most servers use a pool of threads that they reuse rather than create a new thread for each request or even session. If the processing of the first request leaves something in the threadlocal after it's done processing the request, well, that's what the next request will find there.

---

Store the data you need to keep per-session in [HttpServletRequest.getSession()](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/servlet/2.2/javadoc/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getSession()) instead.